# redirect_to leading to a different action than requested

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in Ruby on Rails and this is my first post on stackoverflow.

I have this page where the user can select which features he wants. Since he selected the features, the action brings him to a page where he can see the attributes of the selected features and for each of the selected features there is a link for editing the feature.
I can perfectly edit and update the feature, but I'd like the action update to redirect to that page with the selected features so that the user wouldn't have to select them again.

The problem is that when I do `redirect_to select_multiple_features_path`, it is not leading to the select_multiple action. I'm getting the following error:

---

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FeaturesController#show**

Couldn't find Feature with id=select_multiple

Server output: http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/1382/sfp4.jpg

---

Controllers:

```
  def edit
    @feature = Feature.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @feature = Feature.find(params[:id])    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @feature.update_attributes(params[:feature])
        format.html { redirect_to select_multiple_features_path, notice: 'Feature was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @feature.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def select_multiple
    if params[:features_ids].nil?
      @features = Feature.find(session[:features_ids])
    else
      @features = Feature.find(params[:features_ids])
      session[:features_ids] = params[:features_ids]
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
resources :attached_assets

resources :modifications

resources :maps

resources :coordinates

resources :results do
    collection do
      post 'select_number_of_groups'
    end
end


resources :features do
    collection do
      post 'select_multiple'
    end
end

resources :home

devise_for :users, :path => "auth", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', 
                                                     :sign_out => 'logout', 
                                                     :password => 'secret', 
                                                     :confirmation => 'verification', 
                                                     :unlock => 'unblock', 
                                                     :registration => 'register', 
                                                     :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' 
                                                    }

devise_scope :user do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please show us your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: I edited the post putting the routes.rb

Comment: Please change this 
post 'select_multiple'  to get 'select_multiple' in your routes.rb file, and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route, you're defining your `post` action but you aren't defining your `get` action.
You have to define:

```
get 'features/select_multiple' => 'features#select_multiple'
```

or else it will assume that you're trying to use the #show action by default.

You can use `rake routes` in your console to show all your routes and matching actions